# Python using re.sub to remove after string.

Tags: python, regex

How do i remove everything after `.rtf`  What I have so far removes `.rtf` and everything after it as well.

```
s = 'newyork.pdf.rtf.doc'
actual_file = re.sub(".rtf.+", "", s)
```

returns `newyork.pdf`

Comment: Use a lookbehind: `re.sub(r'(?<=\.rtf).*', '', s)`.  You can also capture the `.rtf` and substitute in the matching group: `re.sub(r'(\.rtf).*', r'\1', s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Option 1***
Use a positive lookbehind `(?<=\.rtf).*`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\.rtf).*', '', s)
'newyork.pdf.rtf'
```

***Option 2***
Capture the `.rtf` and substitute the matching group back in:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\.rtf).*', r'\1', s)
'newyork.pdf.rtf'
```